# Why are brand names in Hindi TV series censored?

Tags: censorship

I was watching a Hindi TV series and I found many instances of brand identity, like cars or mobile phones, are censored.

This was not the only time I noticed it; I've seen it two or three more times. In English series I did not see it.

Is there any significance or reason behind it?

Comment: No money = no branding.

Comment: Could also be laws in India that prevent product placement. While it's not India, I know the UK has very strict laws about ads in shows and even news articles that don't properly disclose that they're supposed to be ads. That's why a lot of American shows that are re-broadcast by the BBC have logos blurred out.

Comment: I think, i have seen product placement in Indian TV shows too, it must be due to money.

Answer (score 2):

TV shows want to earn as much money as they can. Whenever they have an episode with products from different brands, they always ask if that brand wants to advertise in the episode. If they do, the TV show gets free money. If not, then the they blur it out so that they don't give out free advertising. However, sometimes this is not the case. Sometimes, some brands may not want to get associated with a certain TV shows or themes that are portrayed in the episode. This could cause legal issues against the TV show producers if the brand sues them. More info here:

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100612055504AATiIFZ

https://www.quora.com/Why-are-brand-names-on-clothing-often-blurred-out-when-they-are-shown-on-TV